# Get day of the week from GregorianCalendar

Tags: android, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a date and I need to know the day of the week, so I used a GregorianCalendar object but I get back some dates that are incorrect.

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
int i = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

```
mont--;
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
int i = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if(i == 2){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Mon";           
    } else if (i==3){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Tue";
    } else if (i==4){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Wed";
    } else if (i==5){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Thu";
    } else if (i==6){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Fri";
    } else if (i==7){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Sat";
    } else if (i==1){
        dayOfTheWeek = "Sun";
    }
```

Comment: Is it returning the default value (0 or 1 presumably) instead of what you expect?  Show us what you have and what you want.

Comment: when you set month, value should be ( real month - 1). ex) MARCH -> 2, JANUARY -> 0, DECEMBER -> 11. did you set correct month value?

Comment: kingori thanks! that was the problem :)

Comment: I would have to say this isn't locale proof. Also, it's friday, instead of fryday.

Comment: By the way, for non-Android, in Java 8 and later use java.time classes such as `DayOfWeek` enum:  `DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH  ) );`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);
calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

String monthName=calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());//Locale.US);
String dayName=calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());//Locale.US);
```

Comment: example: calendar.set(2015, Calendar.JANUARY, 8, 0, 0, 0);  would be January 8th, 2015

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

I use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library for all date/time related operations. Joda takes into account you locale and gets results accordingly:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
```

or

```
DateTime date = DateTime().now();
```

Day of week (int):

```
date.getDayOfWeek();
```

Day of week (short String) using `toString()` and [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) options:

```
date.toString("EE");
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myGregCal                  // `GregorianCalendar` is a legacy class, supplanted by the modern `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class.
    .toZonedDateTime()     // Convert to `ZonedDateTime`.
    .getDayOfWeek().       // Extract a `DayOfWeek` enum object, one of seven pre-defined objects, one for each day of the week.
    .getDisplayName(       // Automatically localize, generating a `String` to represent the name of the day of the week.
        TextStyle.SHORT ,  // Specify how long or abbreviated.
        Locale.US          // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localization.
    )                      // Returns a `String` object.
```

> Mon

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )              // Get current date for people in a certain region, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.getDayOfWeek()                                           // Extract a `DayOfWeek` enum object.
.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )  // Generate a string representing that day-of-week, localized using the human language and cultural norms of a particular locale.
```

> lundi

## java.time

Convert the troublesome old legacy [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object to a modern java.time object by calling new methods added to the old class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime();
```

Get the `DayOfWeek` enum object for that moment in that time zone.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek();
```

> dow.toString(): WEDNESDAY

Pass these `DayOfWeek` objects around your code rather than passing integers like 1-7 or strings like "MON". By using the enum objects you make your code more self-documenting, provide type-safety, and ensure a range of valid values.

For presentation to the user, ask the `DayOfWeek` object to translate the name of the day of the week to a human language defined in a `Locale`.

```
String output = 
    dow.getDisplayName( 
        TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , 
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH 
    )
;
```

> mercredi

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).