# Gregorian Calendar Date Confusion

Tags: android

I'm confused about how a Gregorian Calendar associates days with numbers. For examples, I instantiate an object

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Toast.makeText(context, "Day: " + cal.DAY_OF_WEEK, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My toast messages keeps dispalying "Day: 7"

Today is Friday, assuming that Sunday = 0, shouldn't the text display "Day: 5"?

It does work when I do the following:

```
int current day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
```

Can someone explain why? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14448029/5202007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting a `7` with `cal.DAY_OF_WEEK`, is that you're actually asking for the value of the constant named `DAY_OF_WEEK` and the value of that field is `7`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK). In other words, `cal.DAY_OF_WEEK` is really equivalent to `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`.

You get the correct answer with `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, because you're then asking for the value of cal's `DAY_OF_WEEK` field.